# How to Delete Specific Data from Database (SQL/PHP)

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a file upload system where a user can upload an image/file with some text, and then it displays it.

I need help figuring out how to be able to delete a post by user command, so if the user posts an image with some text, the user can click a button next to the post and execute a command that deletes that post/image/text.

Here is my database display system:

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "boxofmem", "", "boxofmem_GMSConnect");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<div id='img_div'>";
    echo "<p style='font-family:Roboto;color:white;font-size:20px;'>".$row['text']."</p>";
    echo "<img src='images/".$row['image']."' ' style='width:100%;height:100%;'>";
    echo "</div>";
}

function deletePost() {


$db->query("DELETE from images WHERE id=0");


}

?>
```

Comment: Assign the image's id, you'd need to have ajax, put delete post in another file, then when the user clicks, obtain the id from the click then send the ajax request to deletePost.php that takes that ID and runs your DB query to remove it.   OR , assign radio buttons next to the image, assign the id of that image to it, add a submit button, then on submit use that $_POST variable (the radio variable value) to delete from the DB that ID

Comment: I have a row labeled ID which is a integer with the number 11, but every time I post a new picture and text, the ID is always 0... how do I put the ID into effect? @clearshot66

Comment: $row['id']; assign id="$row['id']";

Comment: @clearshot66 wouldn't I need to turn on AUTO_INCREMENT or something of the sort?

Comment: Do you have ID already tied to the row in the DB?

Comment: @clearshot66 yes

Comment: so no $row['image'] will be tied to a $row['id'] and thus be unique

Comment: @clearshot66 nevermind they are not tied, what should i do?

Comment: @clearshot66 so the ID Is working, but I am curious as to how I get the ID when the user clicks the button

Answer (score 0):

> DELETE FROM table_name WHERE condition;

```
DELETE FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerName='Alfreds Futterkiste';
```